# Access service running on minikube from different machine

Tags: windows, minikube, portforwarding

I use minikube on Windows to launch a web application.
It works perfect locally, if I run command

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/my-application 9000:8080 -n namespace
```

I can open the Application's index page If I enter url *localhost:9000* or *127.0.0.1:9000* to my PC's browser.

But I cannot access the service e.g. from my smartphone (connected to the same router).

**What I have tried:**

- Start a random Java app on my PC (running on port 8080)
- Call this app from my smartphone entering url *192.168.2.199:8080*
- Result: I could access the application from my smartphone, so basically my PC is accessible from other devices within the same network.

**What should work, but does not:**

- Use port forwarding with kubectl like I mentioned above
- Enter *192.168.2.199:9000* to my smartphone's browser
- Instead of the Application's index page I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

**How can I expose my Application running in Minikube on Windows to be able to access by other devices connected to the same router?**

Used hypervisor: HyperV
As far as I know no firewall is enabled on my PC. (I disabled Windows Defender Firewall, and also added port 9000 to the rules)

Comment: I'm not sure about how it works on Windows, but I think you need to create a service for your deployment. The `port-forward` only works from the machien where you runs the command, it no expose the application to the network. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have created a service (with `type=NodePort`), executing `minikube service my-application` opens the proper page in the browser. (In my case this URL: `http://172.17.104.205:31576/web`)

Comment: Does it solved your problem? If you access the ip and port from other computer should work. Verify the firewall rules to permit the access. Let me know if it worked

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think 172.17.104.205 is accessible only from the host machine

Comment: The service type NodePort will open a port in the host, so the access should works if you try to access `http://<node_ip>:<node_port>`, example: `http:// 192.168.2.199:31576`

Comment: service type NodePort opens a port in the minikube's VM, so it can be accessed from the host by entering the VM's IP and the port. But the given port is not accessible from localhost (127.0.0.1), so it cannot be accessed from another devices. However port-forwarding is listening on the host's port (localhost:port), and it should be available from external devices, but it is not. So I totally don't understand what is wrong, or missing.